# c# center label inside of image

Tags: c#, image, label, center

I have label named: "number1" and picture box: "picturebox2". I would like to set label in center of picture box. I placed label in center and on top of picturebox2. By default number1.Text = "99". If button1 is pressed number1.Text is changed to "1" and this brakes center position of label because is 1 char less.

I use this code to make label transparent:

```
        var pos = this.PointToScreen(number1.Location);
        pos = pictureBox2.PointToClient(pos);
        number1.Parent = pictureBox2;
        number1.Location = pos;
        number1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

How can I place label in center of an image when number in label is changed?

Comment: assign a function to the textChanged event of the label, and change the position.

Comment: can you provide me with code... because I am a noob :) sounds good but don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Labels `AutoSize` Property to False, set the `Width` of the Label to the width of the PictureBox and change the `TextAlign` Property to `MiddleCenter`.  That should do what you are asking.